# Nav header moving only to two items and not going to the third item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code for a navigation in tab header using an arrow icon, but its moving to only 2 items and not going to the third item.

**This is the `onclick` function and `useState`**

```js
const [ActiveTab, setActiveTab] = useState("HAIRCUT");
var index = 0;

const HandleTab = (data) => {
  index = (index + 1) % data.length;
  console.log(data[index].category_name);
  setActiveTab(data[index].category_name);
};
```

**This is the `icon` and `TabConatiner` section**

```js
<MainRow>
  {isServicesLoading || services.length === 0 || services.data === undefined ? (
    <></>
  ) : (
    <>
      {" "}
      {services.length !== 0 &&
        services.data?.map((category) => (
          <>
            <div className="lefticon" style={{}}>
              <img src={Left} />
            </div>

            <div onClick={() => HandleTab(services.data)} className="righticon">
              <img src={Right} />
            </div>
          </>
        ))}
      <TabContainer
        defaultActiveKey="HAIRCUT"
        activeKey={ActiveTab}
        onSelect={() => HandleTab(services.data)}
        id="services-tabs"
      >
        {services.length !== 0 &&
          services.data?.map((category, idx) => (
            <TabItem
              eventKey={category.category_name}
              title={
                <>
                  <TitleContainer>
                    <TitleImg src={service[idx].img} />

                    {/* <TitleImg src={category.icon} /> */}
                    <H3>{category.category_name}</H3>
                  </TitleContainer>
                  <TitleContainer>
                    {/* <TitleImg  src={service[idx].img} /> */}
                  </TitleContainer>
                </>
              }
            >
              <div>
                <Col md={12} sm={12}>
                  <Link to={`/service/${category.slug}`}>
                    {" "}
                    <TabContent
                      className="tabservices"
                      service={category.service}
                    />
                  </Link>
                </Col>
              </div>
            </TabItem>
          ))}
      </TabContainer>
    </>
  )}
</MainRow>
```